# How to query all fields from an ActiveRecord model AND one field from its related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

If I have two models `foo` and `bar` that are one to many, how could I query all columns from `foo` and then a single column from `bar` using Rails query interface?

In other words, how would I translate the below query to Rails:

```
select foo.*, bar.col from foo inner join bar on foo.bar_id = bar.id;
```

Comment: This will return multiple `Foo`s one for each related `Bar` is that your intention?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have `Foo`(with table `foos`) and `Bar`(with table `bars`)  as ActiveRecord Models and `Foo` has many `bars`

You can make use of [`joins`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins)  and [`select`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select)

May be something like this:

```rb
Foo.joins(:bars).select("foos.*", "bars.col")
```

Comment: use `select` instead of `pluck`. `pluck` will return an `Array` of those attributes `select` will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` of `Foos` with a virtual attribute of `col` that represents `bar.col`

Comment: @engineersmnky thank you for your input, I updated my answer